# Pentomino solver in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

When I was a child, I used to play [Ubongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubongo) board game, recently I discovered [Pentomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) puzzle and I wanted to create a custom solver in python for it. Here is what I got:

```py
import datetime

def solve(height, width, pieces):
    sorted_pieces = sort_pieces_by_length(pieces) # this makes it faster as it sort also coords of piece
    board = [['' for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
    result = []
    counter = 0

    def is_valid_placement(piece, x, y):
        first_coord = piece[0]
        if not (0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height) or board[y][x] != '':
            return False
        for px, py in piece[1:]:
            nx, ny = x + px - first_coord[0], y + py - first_coord[1]
            if not (0 <= nx < width and 0 <= ny < height) or board[ny][nx] != '':
                return False
        return True

    def place_piece(piece, x, y, char):
        first_coord = piece[0]
        board[y][x] = char
        for px, py in piece[1:]:
            nx, ny = x + px - first_coord[0], y + py - first_coord[1]
            board[ny][nx] = char

    def remove_piece(piece, x, y):
        first_coord = piece[0]
        board[y][x] = ''
        for px, py in piece[1:]:
            nx, ny = x + px - first_coord[0], y + py - first_coord[1]
            board[ny][nx] = ''

    def find_smallest_area():

        visited = set()
        smallest_area = height * width
        occupied_tiles = 0

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                if board[y][x] != '':
                    occupied_tiles += 1

        def bfs(start_x, start_y):
            nonlocal smallest_area
            queue = [(start_x, start_y)]
            area = 0

            while queue:
                curr_x, curr_y = queue.pop(0)
                if (curr_x, curr_y) in visited or not (0 <= curr_x < width and 0 <= curr_y < height) or board[curr_y][curr_x] != '':
                    continue

                visited.add((curr_x, curr_y))
                area += 1

                for dir_x, dir_y in [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]:
                    new_x, new_y = curr_x + dir_x, curr_y + dir_y
                    queue.append((new_x, new_y))

            smallest_area = min(smallest_area, area)

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                if occupied_tiles + len(visited) == height * width:
                    return smallest_area
                if (x, y) not in visited and board[y][x] == '':
                    bfs(x, y)

        return smallest_area

    def rotateR(piece_coords):
        return sorted([[y, -x] for x, y in piece_coords], key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))

    def rotateH(piece_coords):
        return sorted([[-x, y] for x, y in piece_coords], key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))

    def backtrack(piece_index):
        nonlocal result,counter
        counter+=1
        if piece_index == len(sorted_pieces):
            result.append([row[:] for row in board])
            return True

        piece_name, piece_coords = list(sorted_pieces.items())[piece_index]
        reset_coords = piece_coords

        def try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
            if not piece_already_placed(piece_coords, placed_pieces):
                place_piece(piece_coords, x, y, piece_name)
                placed_pieces.append(piece_coords)
                if find_smallest_area() >= 5 and backtrack(piece_index + 1):
                    return True

                remove_piece(piece_coords, x, y)
                return False

        for y in range(height):
            for x in range(width):
                if board[y][x] != '':
                    continue
                placed_pieces = []
                piece_coords = reset_coords

                if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                    if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                        return True

                for _ in range (3):
                    piece_coords = rotateR(piece_coords)

                    if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                        if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                            return True
                piece_coords = reset_coords
                piece_coords = rotateH(piece_coords)

                if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                    if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                        return True

                for _ in range (3):
                    piece_coords = rotateR(piece_coords)

                    if is_valid_placement(piece_coords, x, y):
                        if try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index):
                            return True



        return False
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    backtrack(0)
    print("TOTAL BACKTRACKS",counter)
    print("Time to find: ",(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds(), "sec")

    return result[0]

def sort_pieces_by_length(piece_dict):
    sorted_pieces = dict(sorted(piece_dict.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]),reverse=True))
    for piece_name, piece_coords in sorted_pieces.items():
        sorted_pieces[piece_name] = sorted(piece_coords, key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))
    return sorted_pieces

def piece_already_placed(new_piece, pieces):
    for piece in pieces:
        if are_pieces_same(new_piece, piece):
            return True
    return False


def are_pieces_same(piece1, piece2):
    # Calculate the biases on x and y axes
    piece1 = [coord.copy() for coord in piece1]
    piece2 = [coord.copy() for coord in piece2]
    for coord1, coord2 in zip(piece1, piece2): # move to the positive quadrant
        coord1[0] += 10
        coord1[1] += 10
        coord2[0] += 10
        coord2[1] += 10

    piece1 = sorted(piece1, key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))
    piece2 = sorted(piece2, key=lambda coord: (coord[0], coord[1]))

    bias_x = piece2[0][0] - piece1[0][0]
    bias_y = piece2[0][1] - piece1[0][1]

    # Check if all corresponding coordinates are the same with the calculated biases
    for coord1, coord2 in zip(piece1, piece2):
        if coord1[0] + bias_x != coord2[0] or coord1[1] + bias_y != coord2[1]:
            return False
    return True


print(solve(5, 12, {'F': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]], 'W': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]], 'V': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]], 'X': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]], 'N': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], 'P': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2]], 'U': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]], 'Z': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, -1], [1, -2], [2, -2]], 'I': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4]], 'Y': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0]], 'T': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [-1, 2], [1, 2]], 'L': [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [0, 3]]}))
```

It finds the correct solution, but I wanted to get all the solutions (or at least few more in a reasonable time). I tried to do some optimization, but I think it 100% it is still falling into unnecessary recursive branches.
It finds one solution in **~22** seconds on my PC. I added print for counter of backtracks called and **23k** seems too high.
The **5×12** box has **1010** solutions (Wikipedia).
For sure there are some complex techniques to speed this up, but are there some trivial that could be added to my code?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Kudos on tackling such an interesting problem!

## design of Public API

```
print(solve(5, 12, {'F': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]],
                    'W': ... }))
```

On the one hand, I like the simplicity of representation,
and the very helpful use of standard pentomino names.
On the other hand, I think I'd prefer to see a level of indirection here.
And [x, y] coord lists should definitely become (x, y) tuples.
(Also, trivially, W × H might become a `size` tuple, whatever.)

```
pentominos = {
    'F': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
    'W': ...
}
print(solve((5, 12), 'FWVXNPUZIYTL', pentominos)
```

or perhaps

```
print(solve((5, 12), 'FILNPTUVWXYZ', pentominos)
```

---

## tuple over list

A slightly odd thing about python culture is
that choice of Sequence matters.
Some concepts are a good semantic fit for a
[tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples),
others for a
[list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists),
as James Tauber
[explains](https://jtauber.com/blog/2006/04/15/python_tuples_are_not_just_constant_lists).

Think of an (x, y) `Point` as a C struct or a python tuple.

Or consider an invoice spreadsheet showing the sale
of half a dozen widgets, with columns `part_number`,
`quantity`, `extended_price`.
Each row is a 3-tuple.
And then we have half a dozen `list` entries,
each of them being a 3-tuple.

With tuples position matters, it changes the meaning of the item.
In contrast, a list is a bunch of "same thing", so the
initial item and the final one have similar semantics.

Recommend you prefer (x, y) tuples in this code base,
rather than the [x, y] lists that are currently implemented.

---

## unit tests

This submission tackles a challenging geometry problem.

Yet it includes no automated unit or integration
[tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).
Which makes me sad.
And complicates the life of maintainers, or benchmarkers.

---

## nested functions

The following functions impress me as being "hard to test":

```
    def is_valid_placement(piece, x, y): ...

    def place_piece(piece, x, y, char): ...

    def remove_piece(piece, x, y): ...

    def find_smallest_area(): ...

        def bfs(start_x, start_y): ...

    def rotateR(piece_coords): ...

    def rotateH(piece_coords): ...

    def backtrack(piece_index): ... 

        def try_place(x, y, piece_coords, placed_pieces, piece_index): ...
```

Why?
Because they are nested.
Sometimes even doubly-nested!

Occasionally nesting can be helpful,
when functions should share the same namespace,
should have overlapping access to same variables.
My standard advice on nesting is simple: Don't.
Usually it's not helpful.
(I confess this is the very first time I have
ever seen someone use double nesting
for purposes other than asking whether the
interpreter supports arbitrary nesting.)

Here, we are using some very well thought out
nesting to organize the code.
But it thwarts the efforts of any maintainer
who wants to write a simple unit test
or wants to produce benchmark timings
of two competing implementations,
even something as simple as the use of
[@njit](https://pypi.org/project/numba)
decorator.

Prefer to use modules or classes to
organize the code.
Alternatively, each of these functions
might appear at top-level, just like `solve`.
Use an `_` underscore prefix to suggest that
a `_private` helper is not part of the Public API
that you're exporting.

I feel it would make sense to introduce `class Solver:`
which knows about a collection of `class Pentomino:` shapes.

---

## lint

```
    def rotateR( ... ): ...

    def rotateH( ... ): ...
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you name these `rotate_r` and `rotate_h`.

And then I ask that you spell these out more fully.
At first I thought left / right, cw / ccw (or anti-clockwise for
my British friends), links / rechts, gauche / droit,
but wasn't finding a match.
The OP context suggested your native tongue might possibly be Polish,
but lewy / prawidłowy doesn't work, and clockwise had too
many Z's and W's for a match.

The (y, -x) and (-x, y) transforms suggest that we are Flipping
about a mirror axis, rather than Rotating a shape within the plane.
Recommend that you choose more informative function names,
or at least add a """docstring""" to each one.

The lambdas appear to be superfluous, as each sequence would work on its own.

---

## tuple unpack

This code base makes extensive use of `[0]` subscript
to denote `x` and `[1]` subscript to denote `y`.

Prefer to express this as `x, y = coords`.

Or, much better,
[define](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
a class:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

---

## rotations

```
def sort_pieces_by_length(piece_dict):
    sorted_pieces = dict(sorted(piece_dict.items(),
                                key=lambda item: len(item[1]), reverse=True))
```

I don't understand this function.
In two ways.

It's unclear whether "length" should match "width" or "height".
(The `[1]` subscript tells me "height", but the relationship
isn't obvious to me.)

It's unclear why this is even helpful.
We alternatively might define `max_length`
as the maximum of a piece's width or height,
and then "sort by max_length", in an effort
to make "hard to fit" pieces bubble up toward the front.

Maybe "height" is special because of how we iterate over shapes,
doing `x` and `y` in a certain order?
Maybe it's special because pentominos are conventionally defined
to be "tall", or "squat"?
Maybe there's something else going on here?

Dealing with symmetry is fundamental to solving pentomino-style problems.
This codebase should include ReadMe.md or docstrings that
describe the approach taken.
The L pentomino, for example, has four rotations
and then the flipped form has four rotations.
It might be worth hanging on to all eight copies,
recording them as all part of the same equivalence class,
and trying to fit them into the evolving puzzle.

---

## use builtins

```
def piece_already_placed(new_piece, pieces):
    for piece in pieces:
        if are_pieces_same(new_piece, piece):
            return True
    return False
```

This [is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
def piece_already_placed(new_piece, pieces):
    return any(are_pieces_same(new_piece, piece) for piece in pieces)
```

With judicial use of
[partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)
it would be amenable to a
[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
invocation.

It's possible that
[@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
could help speed this up in nearly its current form,
if we're passing around immutable (hashable!) tuples
instead of lists.

---

## use array for speed

```
    board = [['' for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
```

Lists are nice, but they involve a lot of object pointers.
Prefer a python
[array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html),
or perhaps a numpy
[ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html).

A byte array, without all those object pointers,
will be smaller and more cache friendly.

If you go the numpy route you will be able to use fast vectorized
operations for adding a piece shape to the `board`,
for testing whether a proposed placement caused overlap,
and other useful primitives.

---

## define a class

Uggh! Put this within `class Solver:`, please.

```
    def backtrack( ... ):
        nonlocal result, counter
        counter += 1
        if ... :
            result.append( ... )
```

The declaration for `result` appears to be spurious.
(While the one for `counter` is essential.)
The lookup should succeed even without a declaration,
and then we mutate that object, which is quite
different from assigning a new value to `counter`.

This code appears to be trickier than necessary.

Prefer references to `self.counter` and `self.result`.

---

## sameness

```
def are_pieces_same(piece1, piece2):
    # Calculate the biases on x and y axes
    piece1 = [coord.copy() for coord in piece1]
    piece2 = [coord.copy() for coord in piece2]
    for coord1, coord2 in zip(piece1, piece2):  # move to the positive quadrant
        coord1[0] += 10 ...
```

Thank you for that helpful comment about the magic number `10` -- we're
just translating to the positive quadrant, and a pentomino's size
will never exceed `5`.

The `# Calculate ...` comment could have been a """docstring""".
Except that it wouldn't be a very informative docstring.
So I'm left with the (very nice!) function name to explain this function's
[responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

It leaves me with some questions about what "same" means.

Same w.r.t. translation? rotation? mirror-flipping?

During placement we did some of those transforms.
And now it seems we have to undo them to recover the
identity of the piece.
It makes me sad that we lost track of its identity during placement.

Consider pre-rotating and pre-flipping all pieces at the outset.
The "I" pentomino, for example, is quite boring so it will
expand to fewer entries than "L" will.

You can write five I's, or five L values, into five cells of `board`.

You may find it helpful to attach a summary `bbox`,
a width × height bounding box, to each piece variant,
so e.g. a vertical "I" or a horizontal "I" can be
quickly ruled out from certain proposed solutions.

---

This code appears to achieve a subset of its design goals.
Speedup is the principle aim of future development.
Changes to how we represent pieces, and the board, hold some promise for that.

There are no automated tests in this submission,
and substantial changes would be needed in order to introduce them.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance
tasks on this codebase.

Comment: Thanks for detailed review, I will update the code based on your recommendations.